# MS Access 2007 Report Group by Xs is missing an entry on the 1st group

Tags: ms-access, grouping, report

I was experimenting with MS Access 2007 on how to create a report with 4 data on each page. However, on the first group it only shows 3 data and the rest contains 4. Here's what I did:

1. I have a sample table with 2 fields: ID and Product. ID is a AutoNumber and Product is Text datatype.
2. I created a report with the table as the source and placed 1 textbox
   for the ID field.
3. Set the columns to 2 in page setup and adjust the width to fit in the page.
4. Add a grouping on the Details section using the ID and set it by every 4s (custom) and left the other options as is.
5. Added sorting on the same ID and left the other options as is.
6. Set the group header to none visible or height = 0 and set Force a new page to Before Section.

Now, when I check the print preview the 1st page only shows 3 IDs while the rest shows 4. Why is that? I tried changing the properties but can't get it right. Could someone help? Is there another solution to this? What I want is to create a page with 4 records on it, kinda like printing 4 slides in a page in PowerPoint.